# What is the <comment> tag?

Tags: html, tags

I found a tag that I had never seen before in some HTML code : what is the `<comment>Some comment</comment>` tag and how is it different from the `<!-- Another comment -->` ?

**EDIT** : Here is the piece of code.

```
    <object 
    classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" 
    codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.5.0/jinstall-1_5-windows-i586.cab#Version=5,0,0,5" 
    width="130" height="25" name="SmartCardSignerApplet"> 
    <param name="code" value="SmartCardSignerApplet"> 
    <param name="archive" value="SmartCardSignerApplet.jar"> 
    <param name="mayscript" value="true"> 
    <param name="type" value="application/x-java-applet;version=1.5"> 
    <param name="scriptable" value="false"> 
    <param name="fileNameField" value="fileToBeSigned"> 
    <param name="certificationChainField" value="certificationChain"> 
    <param name="signatureField" value="signature"> 
    <param name="signButtonCaption" value="Sign selected file"> 

    <comment> 
        <embed 
            type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.5" 
            code="SmartCardSignerApplet" archive="SmartCardSignerApplet.jar" 
            width="130" height="25" scriptable="true" 
            pluginspage="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/index.html#download" 
            fileNameField="fileToBeSigned" 
            certificationChainField="certificationChain" 
            signatureField="signature" 
            signButtonCaption="Sign selected file"> 
        </embed> 
        <noembed> 
            Smart card signing applet can not be started because 
            Java Plugin 1.5 or newer is not installed. 
        </noembed> 
    </comment> 
</object>
```

Comment: Can you provide some source of where did you saw this?

Comment: Not sure but you might have misleaded I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `<comment>` element in HTML (a list of elements which *are* in the language appears in [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1)). Browsers will treat it like any other non-standard tag and perform error recovery (inserting it into the DOM with default styling).